# append api response to select list

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have get ajax code

```
$.ajax({
    url: "api/librarian/list/callno",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        if(data.success) {
            $.each(data.data, function (index, value) {
                $('#book_callno_list').append('<option>'+value+'</option>');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

i want to append returned data in select list with is **`book_callno_list`** but `console.log(data)` show data like this , how can i get each data ???

**ajax response**

[image]

Comment: can you please post your complete code here?

Comment: use `$.each(data.Data,...`

Comment: All this fuss over a typo.. also if people stopped using useless jQuery they would get more prompts on invalid and/or undefined accessed objects.

Answer (score 0):

The response of the server say:

You have a object "Data" and that "Data" has a array of items.

If you want to access a object and then get the list inside you need to access it this way:

```
response.data[item].
```

The console.log(data) is just showing what the returned response is, if you do console log inside the .each, you get what you want.

you need to iterate over: data.Data, not data.data

Answer (score 0):

For me you can go like this:

```js
var data={ success:true }
data.Data=["A-1","A-2","A-3","A-4","B-1","B-2","B-3","B-4","C-1","C-2","C-3","C-4","D-1","D-2"];

    if(data.success) {

    $.each(data.Data, function(key, value) {   
        $('#monselect')
            .append($("<option></option>")
                       .attr("value",key)
                       .text(value)); 
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="monselect">
 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry i'm try each response but just

```
$.ajax({
    url: "api/librarian/list/callno",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        if(data.success) {
            $.each(data.data.Data, function (index, value) {
                $('#book_callno_list').append('<option>'+value+'</option>');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

work successfully .